# How to display data in a datagrid

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a class name cal.class. the function perform a loan calculation. it read the interest rate from a database and perform the calculation based on the amount input. I want to display the result in a data grid. for e.g `InterestRate`, `MonthlyPayment`, `TotalPayment`. I don't know how to do it.

Below is what I have I tried:

Cal.class

```
Public Shared Sub Calculator(ByVal _Source As String, ByVal _LoanAmount As Double, ByVal _LoanType As String,ByVal _Years As Double)
        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand
        Dim SConn As String = ClsConnStr.GetConnString(_Source)
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(SConn)
            Dim MonthlyPayment As Double
            Dim MonthlyInterestRate As Double
            Dim TotalPayment As Double

            conn.Open()
            myCommand.Connection = conn
            Dim daReader As SqlDataReader

            Dim Sql As String = "Select Interestrate AS RESULT  from tblloan where LoanType =  '" & _LoanType & "'"
            Dim scmd As New SqlCommand(Sql, conn)
            daReader = scmd.ExecuteReader()

            If daReader.HasRows Then
                While daReader.Read()

                    MonthlyInterestRate = (daReader("RESULT")) / 1200
                    MonthlyPayment = _LoanAmount * MonthlyInterestRate / (1 - 1 / Math.Pow(1 + MonthlyInterestRate, _Years * 12))
                    TotalPayment = MonthlyPayment * _Years * 12

                End While
            End If
            conn.Close()
        End Using

    End Sub
```

I call the method: `cal.Calculator("TEST", "5000", "FS", "5")`

and I have a data grid in my form.

Comment: I recommend that you read the documentation of DataGridView. Certainly the part [DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: can you help me in term of code

Comment: this is too broad to handle in one question. I can show you the steps but it is you who need to understand wat is happening.

Comment: Stef is right. The online docs have some great examples: fill a dataset or datatable, then databind it to a grid.  Here on Stackoverflow, we usually answer questions when you get stuck and show you the mistake in your code. We usually don't give tutorials or how-to answers.  Give the online docs a try and if you get stuck, come back and let us help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataTable with the column headers and datatypes you need.

Include your command in the Using...End Using block. You can pass your connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. Also, you can pass the command text and the connection to the constructor of the command.

Add rows to the DataTable in the While loop

```
Public Shared Function Calculator(ByVal _Source As String, ByVal _LoanAmount As Double, ByVal _LoanType As String, ByVal _Years As Double) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Monthly Interest Rate", GetType(Decimal))
    dt.Columns.Add("Monthly Payment", GetType(Decimal))
    dt.Columns.Add("Total Payment", GetType(Decimal))
    Dim SConn As String = ClsConnStr.GetConnString(_Source)
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(SConn),
            myCommand As New SqlCommand("Select Interestrate AS RESULT  from tblloan where LoanType = @LoanType", conn)
        myCommand.Parameters.Add("@LoanType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _LoanType
        conn.Open()
        Using daReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader
            If daReader.HasRows Then
                While daReader.Read()
                    Dim col1 = CDbl(daReader("RESULT")) / 1200
                    Dim col2 = _LoanAmount * col1 / (1 - 1 / Math.Pow(1 + col1, _Years * 12))
                    Dim col3 = col2 * _Years * 12
                    dt.Rows.Add({CDec(col1), CDec(col2), CDec(col3)})
                End While
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Your call parameters are wrong. You cannot pass a Double as a String (enclosed in quote)

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt = Calculator("TEST", 5000, "FS", 5)
    'You will probably have to add formatting to the grid
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```